# Order of precedence

Tags: c++

This is a really simple question, but I'm afraid it's a bit tricky.

Which of the following symbols has the highest precedence? (C++)

a. %

b. -

c. ||

d. &&

I know it sounds easy, but I'm really wondering if whether the answer is % or -. The symbol - can be seen as either a unary minus (which is higher than %) or subtraction (which is lower than %).

What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, was too hasty. The question is ill-posed for the reason you state. Whoever made that question messed up.

Comment: Circle a and b and make a note on the paper that it depends on whether `-` is the unary negation or binary subtraction operator. If it's an online assignment that won't let you choose two or leave an extra note, most system have a comments section for the quiz as a whole (or a way to contact the setter). Just leave them a note there.

Answer (score -1):

A google search for `c++ Operator Precedence` yielded this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

According to the link,  `Multiplication, division, and remainder` come before `Addition and subtraction` and further down the list comes the `Bitwise operations` found in row `5`,`6`,`13`, and `14` respectively.

Answer (score -2):

I would assume the person who made this question wanted you to choose the operator  that has the highest **possible** precedence.

I would choose **b**.